# Css-sprites animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-sprites, sprite

I have an animation using css-sprites. The animation works in webkit and mozilla. Can anyone suggest how I get this to work in IE? I guess I need some javascript?
http://www.arc-bpictures.com/anim.html
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/zQeaa/

Answer (score 0):

you are using CSS3 animation with sprites, with the prefixes -webkit and -moz.  (You should have posted this code to save us the time).  But anyway, IE does not support keyframe animations yet.  I'd recommend a jscript library such as [spritely](http://spritely.net/) for cross-browser support.

Comment: Thanks for this and sorry for the delay and misunderstanding. Anyway I appreciate your help. Thanks